# Как распарсить строку выдачи cat -n

Tags: bash

Как получить в отдельные переменные номер строки и значение после вывода команды `cat -n alfabet.txt` 
Предположим в файле 5 строк, в каждой строке буква алфавита по порядку. Если вывести 4 строку, то консоль выдаст "4 г".

Каким образом в переменную $count внести 4, а в $word "г"?

Comment: `read count word <<< $(команда)`

Comment: Прочтите внимательнее вопрос. Речь идёт о выдаче команды "cat"

Comment: `read count word <<< $(cat опции-и-параметры)`

Comment: Пробую в debian read count <<< $( cat alph.txt -n | grep 2  ); echo $count Выводит 2 b.
Изначальная проблема в том, что консоль не обрабатывает номер строки (cat -n), как строку. И вопрос в том, как получить этот самый номер строки в выдаче команды cat.
А в таком виде, выдачи вообще нет read count <<< $( cat alph.txt -n | cut -d " " -f 1,2,3,4,5 );

Comment: [mcve].........

Comment: Потому что надо отучаться от bash, и писать на чистом переносимом shell’е. Скажу сразу — это довольно трудный язык программирования.

Comment: Кому и для чего это нужно?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Предлагаю на суд читателя такой вариант решения:

```
echo {a..z} | tr ' ' '\n' > alphabet.txt
while read count word; do
  echo "count=$count, word=$word"
done < <(cat -n alphabet.txt)
```

Comment: Да! Это именно то, что нужно! Спасибо большое!
Ещё один вопрос, почему в консоли выдача "номеров" cat -n без дополнительного кода не может считываться в переменную?

Comment: Не очень понимаю Ваш вопрос... cat -n выводит не одну строку ведь, а все строки, предваряя их номерами. Что именно Вы хотели бы записать в переменную? Если все номера строк, то можно и так. Показать как? P.S. Если мой ответ Вас устраивает, буду признателен, если Вы отметите его как решение. Спасибо!

Comment: Не очень доступно выразился: cat -n выводит в первой колонке номера строк, но обратиться к ним без вашего кода =) нельзя, хотя с виду это обычные цифры, почему так и почему их сразу нельзя использовать в коде, например для переменных?

Comment: Снова не вполне Вас понял. Номер строки можно сходу получать без cat -n вот так:
declare -i line_num=1; while read line; do echo "count=$((line_num++)), word=$line"; done <alphabet.txt

Comment: Ну это уже небольшой скрипт перебора строк со счётчиком, вопрос именно в выводе команды cat. Банальный пример - если я вывожу список файлов и их параметров программой ls -lah, любые столбцы вывода я могу обрабатывать, как обычные строки, разбив вывод на колонки тем же cut'ом. А разбить на колонки вывод cat -n alphabet.txt | cut -d " " -f 1 - чтобы получить только первый столбец с цифрами не удаётся. Собственно в этом и  вопрос - что не так с cat )
В любом случае ваш код работает, спасибо!

Comment: Дмитрий, не так уж всё и плохо с cat'ом, просто не всегда разделитель колонок - это какой-то один фиксированный символ. Например, так вполне можно получить номера строк: cat -n /etc/fstab | awk -F '[[:space:]]+' '{print $2}'

Comment: Ясно! Ещё раз большое Вам спасибо!